# Why should a Scala program have a main method or extend the App trait?

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn Scala by reading the book "Scala for the Impatient". The book starts out saying to enter code into the REPL, but that became kind of tedious, so I started putting my code in a file and then running it from the command line by typing `scala myApp.scala`. Everything seemed to work fine. I decided to make my programs a bit easier to run by putting the line `#!/usr/bin/env scala` at the top, so I could just type `./myFile.scala` from the command line. Everything continued to work fine.

Later, the book says "Each Scala program must start with an object's `main` method..." and gives an example of that. Immediately after that, it says "Instead of providing a `main` method for your application, you can extend the `App` trait and place the program code into the constructor body" and give an example of that.

**Why would I want to do any of those things?**

I tried putting my code in the `main` method of an object, and it still worked, but the object and the `main` method seem like useless cruft to me.

I tried putting my code in an object that extends `App` and it didn't do anything when I tried to run it directly from the command line. It worked fine when I ran it through `scalac` and then ran `scala MyApp`, but those seem like useless steps for the small toy projects I'm working on.

What is the purpose of having an object with the `main` method, or an object that extends `App`?

**EDIT:** Someone marked this question as a duplicate of "The difference between scala script and application". I would say it is arguably not a duplicate, since it is because it is about having `main` methods and extending from `App`, and not about the meaning of the words "script" and "application". However, it is quite close, so my question may be unnecessary. I don't know how this question should be treated. Feel free to close it or leave it open as you see fit.

Answer (score 5):

There may be no purpose if all you are doing are the "small toy projects" you are working on. For larger projects, a `main()` method creates compatibility with Java, and also indicates to the reader of your code "where it all starts". When a project is large (hundreds and thousands of files) and you come in contact with it for the first time, you may want to know "how do I run this?", "where does execution start?". Java took this convention from C++, which took it from C. C is all made of functions, and you need to tell the compiler which function needs to be compiled into the "start of execution".
When you execute your code by hand, you say "scala myApp.scala", which explains to the Scala interpreter which class to execute. But if you write a larger app, compile two classes and put them in a JAR, you need a way to tell the JVM what to execute first: you specify the name of an object, within which (by convention) execution will start at `main(args: Array[String])`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your small programs are displaying results without a main method is because you are not actually using the scala compiler. The program is simply using the scala interpreter.
So a program like:

`A.scala:`

```
println("just the interpreter")
```

Will run and give results. However, trying to compile this program with scalac will produce an error:
`A.scala:1: error: expected class or object definition`

Normally scala projects are not a list of instructions in 1 file. As soon as you start architecting your application with classes and objects, you will see that you programs don't produce any results.

`B.scala:`

```
object B {
    println("won't show up")
}
```

To get results you need to add a main method to tell scala where the entry point into your application is.

`C.scala:`

```
object C {
    def main(args: Array[String]) =
        println("shows up")
}
```

For convenience the App trait allows you to turn any object into an executable program by simply extending App. Extending this trait turns the entire objects body into the main method.

`D.scala:`

```
object D extends App {
    println("shows up")
}
```

Now you can't simply call `scala D.scala` to get results. You first need to call `scalac D.scala`, then you can call `scala D`, and you will get the result you expected.

`scala C.scala` only works because an object with a main defined explicitly is a special case handled by the scala interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You can run programs using both of the methods. But Scripts are used for small programs while declaring `main` method is used for large programs. Traditionally JVM on which the byte code runs recognises the `main` method and starts executing the program starting from the first line of the main method.